# What is the shortest google redirection query parameters for any URL?

Tags: google-chrome, plsqldeveloper, google-url-shortener

For example in query search we have :

```
GoogleUrl/search?q=
```

It will display the search queries, So for redirection is there any shortest parameter?

For example in redirection `cd=value` is used for site at which position.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you extend it with a few full examples?

Comment: For search query we have Google.com/search?q=    where q= searched keywords                    Similarily after search if we click on any site first it redirect to any Url then go to its original site address...     So what is the simplified query for opening a site https://www.google.com/url?sa=&rct=&q=&esrc=source=&cd=&cad=act=&ved=&url=&ei=&usg=